# listview id is not detected

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, listviewitem

I am trying to import my ListView but for some reason my program cannot detect my listview ID.  I have tried cleaning project and restarting eclipse but i am getting the same results

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstlist);
        testcontacts = getResources()
                .getStringArray(R.array.testcontacts_array);

        aa = new MessageView();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my Listview xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#cc252a"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="This will be Changed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here are my list view items format:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Some more information" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Some Information" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it supposed to be

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
```

instead of

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Comment: `@android:id/list` is correct only for use with a `ListActivity`, which would automatically detect the `ListView` with that ID in the XML file.